# Frobenius actions on cohomology of abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a finite field $k$. Let $V_\ell(A)$ be its $\ell$-adic Tate module.

We have a natural action of the absolute Galois group of $k$, and thus an action of the Frobenius automorphism of $\overline{k}$ on $V_\ell(A)$.

However, $A$ also has an endomorphism $F:A\to A$ which also acts on $V_\ell(A)$ (only as an endomorphism a priori).

Are these endomorphisms of $V_\ell(A)$ the same?
I am sure they are, but why? I have seen this used many times, and I'm slightly confused about it...

Comment: What do you think are the definitions of these two endomorphisms?

Comment: I found the introduction of Deligne's Weil I very helpful for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Does http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/Jannsen/home/Weil-gesamt-eng.pdf p. 29, Theorem 5.4 help you? One has $T_\ell A = H^1_\mathrm{et}(\bar{A},\mathbf{Z}_\ell)^\vee$.